# Get WMTS tile row, column, and zoom for coordinates in EPSG:3857

Tags: python, wmts, ogc

I am writing an SDK that will allow users to enter coordinates in EPSG:3857 and a zoom level (long, lat, zoom) and return a tile row, column, and zoom. The end goal is for this tile row, column, and zoom to be piped into a WMTS service and return a tile.

```
#What I want:
input = (-11688138, 4830820, 16)
myFunc(input)
Out[1]: (x=24868, y=13654, z=16)
```

I thought using the [mercantile](https://github.com/mapbox/mercantile) library would work by doing this:

```
mercantile.tile(-11688138, 4830820, 16)
```

However, it turns out the `mercantile.tile` function only accepts coordinates in EPSG:4326 and therefore returns tiles in the same projection.

Converting my 3857 coordinates to 4326 coordinates and then using the function won't work because then the resulting tiles will be in the wrong TileMatrixSet.

It doesn't look like there's anyway to do what I need using the mercantile library, but I feel like there should be. What am I missing here? I would also be okay using another function if anyone has one that does what I'm looking for.

Comment: Formula is very simple, see here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Derivation_of_tile_names

Comment: That formula does not work for coordinates in EPSG:3857